# how to trigger Jenkins remote build and pass file as parameter

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to pass file as parameter in Jenkins with remote build trigger.
For this, I am using a token and passing it in simple html get request.
With simple String parameters, it works fine.

But how to pass file as parameter ?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Vighnesh Pai : Even I face a similar use case. From Job A, wanted to trigger Job in a Remote Server. Job B is parameterized and takes file as an input. I use Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin. If I pass the file in Load parameters from external file field of Job A, its not getting read properly in the  Job B